# ReactNative: Two for in the same function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm doing a monitoring from two different device and I should perform some actions in parallel (or almost).

So I have a function

```
dataReceived() {
this.timestampCheckRight(this.props.arrayTimestampRight)
this.timestampCheckLeft( this.props.arrayTimestampLeft)
//...
// there I use the this.timeRealRight and this.timeRealLeft
}

timestampCheckRight( timestampRight ){
  let int_max = 65536;
  let baseRight = 0;
  let diffRight;


  for( let i = 0; i < timestampRight.length; i++){
    diffRight = (( baseRight + timestampRight[i] ) - this.containerRight )
    if( diffRight < 0 ){
      baseRight += int_max;
      diffRight += baseRight
    }
    this.timeRealRight.push(diffRight)
  }
  return (this.timeRealRight)
}

timestampCheckLeft( timestampLeft ){
  let baseLeft = 0;
  let diffLeft;
  let int_max = 65536;

 for(let i = 0; i < timestampLeft.length; i++){
    diffLeft = (( baseLeft + timestampLeft[i] ) - this.containerLeft )
    
    if( diffLeft < 0 ){
      baseLeft += int_max
      diffLeft += baseLeft
    }
    this.timeRealLeft.push(diffLeft)
  }

  return (this.timeRealLeft)
}
```

Now my problem is that sometimes these this.timeRealRight and this.timeRealLeft as like value NaN maybe because the execute doesn't wait until they are complete or other.

How can I do to execute this two function `this.timestampCheckRight(this.props.arrayTimestampRight) this.timestampCheckLeft( this.props.arrayTimestampLeft)`  and obtain the correct value and not NaN ??

The array that I pass is full of values, so it's not the error.

Thank you.

Comment: you are returning an array

Comment: Do you mean that I don't need to return?

Comment: My problem is for example that one of two array is populated correctly the second one no. (only NaN)